# Matching string with regex

Tags: regex, grep

I keep banging my head against the wall looking for a regex that matches a string like any of these:

```
--7928ae02-A--
--7928ae02-B--
--7928ae02-F--
--7928ae02-H--
--7928ae02-Z--
```

the string is two dashes, 8 characters of any letter or number, a dash, an uppercase A-Z and two dashes.

Here's any example of where I'm at:

```
grep '^--[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[A-Z]--$'
```

Comment: Did you use the `grep -P` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work

```
grep -E -- '^--[[:alnum:]]{8}-[[:upper:]]--$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the

```
grep -P '^--[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[A-Z]--$'
```

with the `-P` or `-E` flag. `-P` interprets the regex as a Perl regex, `-E` runs the regex in extended mode. This regex allows all kinds of bells and whistles Like the `{}`-operator.

Running this on your given tests, they all pass.

Comment: note that you only need the extended-regex `-E` flag to enable `{}` quantifiers. `-P` is great for a number of things but is probably overkill for this problem

Comment: True, but this is not overkill: all regexs are compiled and matched using the same time complexity. Perhaps with a small overhead.